# Angular JS filters

Tags: angularjs, return, angularjs-filter

I have a string contained in a member to modify and bind to the title attribute of a label.
i want to modify the string member using angular Filter. The modification will be based on a object that should be passed to the filter function.

help with the syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code i have tried

```
label class="membername" title={{member.name}}

$scope.dalTitleFilter = function (member) {
                return function (value) {

                };
            };
```

Comment: And What have you tried?

Comment: i have added the code..please check

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the filter on your module:

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .filter('length', function () {
        return function(value) {
            if (value && value.length) {
                return value.length;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value" />
<p>{{value | length}}</p>
```

If you want to pass parameters to the filter function (returned from the filter block), you just add arguments to the function:

```
return function(value, argument1, argument2) {

    // Do something with argument1 and argument2

    if (value && value.length) {
        return value.length;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value" />
<p>{{value | length:argument1:argument2}}</p>
```